# traceroute / timezone issues

Tags: networking, traceroute, time-zone

I've had some issues with my windows location reporting as the entrance to some mall in Israel, even though I am in Massachusetts. The traceroute to google has a weird 2nd hop (10.61.22.67) that I can't directly ping. However immediately after that is regular comcast IP addresses in mass and New York and finally to Texas. Any idea on why I would be getting Israel on only windows? Additionally, any idea why there's a 10.61.22.67 IP directly after mine, even though next hop is my normal public IP? I am in an apartment tower so would that be why? It seems to be exclusively windows systems. edge or firefox, chrome or bing or apple maps. Time zone is affected as well, also trying to automatically set me as israel time. every ip in the list of hops to google dns is showing on websites as stateside, as well.

Thanks for any help!

[tracert results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAHUA.png)

[where it thinks I am](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HJpk.png)

Comment: IP geolocation is unreliable at best. There's a reason that most devices that require more accurate location do not use it, but instead use actual location via GPS, or possibly lookups based on connected cellular towers or WiFi signals.

Comment: @music2myear I feel like the opposite side of the globe is a drastic difference for ip geolocation, especially when every hop has their individual geolocations as populating properly (including my own public IP). If anyone can shed some light on how exactly ip geolocation is determined and how it could be so out of loop, I would be very curious.

Comment: If your question is how it works, this is pretty well documented in the internet. Here's a quick search that can get you started down this rabbit hole: https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+does+ip+geolocation+work

Comment: From what I understand, they orgs get their ips from the regional internet registries of their respective service region. Israel is not part of ARIN.